# SQL Server Error The multi-part identifier .. could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, cursor, identifier, multipart

Below is a portion of a stored procedure I'm working on (the snippet can be executed) which returns the error

> The multi-part identifier "CountCursor.ID" could not be bound.

But why?

```
DECLARE @MANTECCount int
DECLARE @ThirdPartyCount int
DECLARE @MemberNo nchar(4)

SET @MANTECCount = 0
SET @ThirdPartyCount = 0
SET @MemberNo = NULL

DECLARE CountCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT ID 
FROM CIF

OPEN CountCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM CountCursor

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @MemberNo = CountCursor.ID 


FETCH NEXT FROM CountCursor;
END;
CLOSE CountCursor;
DEALLOCATE CountCursor;
```

Comment: portion of a stored procedure is missing

Comment: Have you heard of the "into" part of the `fetch` statement?

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the fetched value from `Cursor`(CountCursor) into a variable to use it inside Cursor. More info on Cursor's can be found [*here*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

```
Declare @id int
......
FETCH NEXT FROM CountCursor into @id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @MemberNo = @id
FETCH NEXT FROM CountCursor into @id;
END;
....
```

**Note:** Cursor's can have awful performance. If you add the original code we can try and change it to **SET Based Approach** code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fetch the value into something.  At first, I was wondering about the code structure, then I realized that Python (and probably other languages) treat cursors the same way.

In any case, you can put the value directly into `@MemberNo`:

```
DECLARE @MANTECCount int;
DECLARE @ThirdPartyCount int;
DECLARE @MemberNo nchar(4);

SET @MANTECCount = 0;
SET @ThirdPartyCount = 0;
SET @MemberNo = NULL;

DECLARE CountCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ID 
    FROM CIF;

OPEN CountCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM CountCursor INTO @MemberNo;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM CountCursor INTO @MemberNo;
END;

CLOSE CountCursor;
DEALLOCATE CountCursor;

GO
```

I'm not sure what the code should be doing.  Presumably, you have more interesting code than this.